# Does scala offer async non-blocking IO when working with files?

Tags: scala, akka, reactive-programming

I am using scala 2.10 and I wonder If there is some package which has async IO when working with files?

I did some search o this topic but mostly found examples as following

```
val file = new File(canonicalFilename)
val bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))
bw.write(text)
bw.close()
```

what essentially  essentially java.io package with blocking IO operations - write, read etc. I also found [scala-io](https://github.com/scala-incubator/scala-io) project with this intention but it seems that project is dead last activity 2012.

What is best practice in this scenario? Is there any scala package or the common way is wrapping java.io code to Futures and Observables ?

My use case is from an Akka actor need to manipulate files on local or remote file system. Need to avoid blocking. Or is there any better alternative?

Thnaks for clarifing this

Comment: You're already using Akka - send a message.

Comment: Sorry I probably didn't get it. From within an actor's response body I need to write to a file. I am trying to avoid to block on bw.write

Comment: Yes, send a message and have another actor do it.

Comment: That would be async, but still blocking.

Comment: Exactly, that is what I am about to avoid

Comment: All IO is blocking _somewhere_. It's just a question of making it not block the execution thread.

Comment: To illustrate my point - read [the documentation for `AsynchronousFileChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html) - all it does is submit the task to an `ExecutorService`. Which is exactly what sending a message to another actor would do...

Comment: I believe Akka Streams has support for reading in a file and running various transformations if necessary.  I think you can do this by using a `akka.stream.scaladsl.Source` from an `Iterable` that is the `lines` from a `scala.io.Source`.

Comment: I need write a binary file,  heck existence etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Scala** does not offer explicit API for asynchronous file IO, **however** the plain Java API is exactly the right thing to use in those cases (this is actually a good thing, we can use all these nice APIs without any wrapping!). You should look into using [java.nio.channels.AsynchronousFileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html), which is available since JDK7 and makes use of the underlying system async calls for file IO.

**Akka IO**, while not providing file IO in it's core, has a module developed by Dario Rexin, which allows to use AsynchronousFileChannel with Akka IO in a very simple manner. Have a look at this library to make use of it: https://github.com/drexin/akka-io-file

In the *near future* Akka will provide File IO in its [**akka-streams**](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/current/scala.html) module. It may be as an external library for a while though, we're not exactly sure yet where to put this as it will require users to have JDK at-least 7, while most of Akka currently supports JDK6. Having that said, streams based asynchronous back-pressured file IO is coming soon :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using scalaz-stream for your async support it has [file functionality](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream/blob/master/src/main/scala/scalaz/stream/nio/file.scala) that's built on the `java.nio` async APIs - that's probably the approach I'd recommend. If you're using standard scala futures possibly you can use [akka-io](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/io.html)? which I *think* uses Netty as a backend. Or you can call NIO directly - it only takes a couple of lines to adapt a callback-based API to scalaz or scala futures.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but my understanding was that akka-io currently supports just TCP and UDP

Comment: Oh maybe. The scalaz-stream approach is the one I use myself, akka-io was just something I'd heard about from others.

Comment: While Akka IO does not direcly implement file IO it is possible to use Dario Rexin's [akka-io-file](https://github.com/drexin/akka-io-file) module to extend Akka IO to be able to work with AsynchronousFileChannel from java.nio. :-)