# What is the current state of asynchronous file IO in akka streams?

Tags: scala, file-io, akka, nio, akka-stream

**Target:**

I would like to see Akka's file IO to be as asynchronous and non-blocking as possible.

**My status of knowledge so far:**

In [older project documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/current/scala/stream-io.html#streaming-file-io) you can read this:

> Note
>
> Since the current version of Akka (2.3.x) needs to support JDK6, the
>   currently provided File IO implementations are not able to utilise
>   Asynchronous File IO operations, as these were introduced in JDK7 (and
>   newer). Once Akka is free to require JDK8 (from 2.4.x) these
>   implementations will be updated to make use of the new NIO APIs (i.e.
>   AsynchronousFileChannel).

The current akka version is '2.5.4'. The current version of akka-stream is '2.11' or '2.12'. In the [current documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-io.html#streaming-file-io) the note from abhove is missing and it is only explicitly mentioned that file IO means blocking operations which are processed by a dispatcher dedicated to IO operations.

In the 'MANIFEST.MF' file inside the akka-streams Jar-File there is a line:

```
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
```

So I guess it requires Java 8.

There is [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27734816/573215) related to scala asynchronous file IO but its from January 2015. [One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27770721/573215) contains:

> Akka IO, while not providing file IO in it's core, has a module
>   developed by Dario Rexin, which allows to use AsynchronousFileChannel
>   with Akka IO in a very simple manner. Have a look at this library to
>   make use of it: https://github.com/drexin/akka-io-file

**Questions:**

1. How asynchronous is the current state of akka streams file IO?
2. Does akka streams file IO use 'AsynchronousFileChannel' from Java's NIO?
3. Do I have to do something to use 'AsynchronousFileChannel' from Java's NIO?

Comment: There is no, to my knowledge, non-blocking asynchronous file IO in Java. The NIO2 extension take an ExecutorService to perform the blocking IO operations on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How asynchronous is the current state of akka streams file IO?

Perusing the [source code](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.4/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/impl/io/FilePublisher.scala) shows that Akka Stream's FileIO uses `java.nio.ByteBuffer` and `java.nio.channels.FileChannel`. And as the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.4/scala/stream/stream-io.html#streaming-file-io) states, the file IO operations run in isolation on a dedicated dispatcher.

There is an open [pull request](https://github.com/akka/akka/pull/23217) that attempts to use `AsynchronousFileChannel`. Based on the benchmark results reported in that PR, the PR might be closed in favor of trying a newer approach with synchronous NIO as captured in another [PR](https://github.com/akka/akka/pull/21801).

> 2. Does akka streams file IO use 'AsynchronousFileChannel' from Java's NIO?

No.

> 3. Do I have to do something to use 'AsynchronousFileChannel' from Java's NIO?

This question is moot, because Akka Streams does not use `AsynchronousFileChannel`.